# Computing problems of the form $P(A|B\cap C)$

Tags: probability

Suppose 3 factories, $F_1$, $F_2$, and $F_3$, make bolts, with the probability
 of a bolt being made in each factory being $P(F_1)=4/7$, $P(F_2)=2/7$ and $P(F_3)=1/7$ respectively.

Bolts produced by Factory 1 are defective independently with probability 0.02, so, $P(D|F_1)=0.02$.
Bolts produced by Factory 2 are defective independently with probability 0.02, so, $P(D|F_2)=0.02$. Bolts produced by Factory 3 are defective independently with probability 0.05, so, $P(D|F_3)=0.05$.

Given that two bolts are selected from a batch of bolts from a particular factory and found to be defective, I'm trying to find the probability that the third bolt selected from this batch is also defective. I presume that I need to compute $P(D_3|D_1 \cap D_2)$.

I've attacked the problem as follows, but it doesn't seem to be leading me anywhere helpful:

$$P(D_3|D_1 \cap D_2) = \frac {P(D_3\cap D_1 \cap D_2)}{P(D_1\cap D_2)}$$ $$ = \frac {P(D_1|D_2 \cap D_3)P(D_2|D_3)P(D_3)}{P(D_1 \cap D_2|F_1)P(F_1)+P(D_1 \cap D_2|F_2)P(F_2) + P(D_1 \cap D_2|F_3)P(F_3)} $$

Comment: when it says "bolts are defective independently" what this means? Independently of what? It seems there is only one $D$, not three $D_1$, $D_2$ and $D_3$ as you thought.

Comment: The event that the first bolt selected is defective is $D_1$, the event that the second bolt selected is defective is $D_2$, the event that the third bolt selected is defective is $D_3$.

Comment: the probability to be defective, without taking in account the factory, is (using the law of total probability) $$P(D)=\sum_{k=1}^3P(D|F_k)P(F_k)$$ I guess that the probability to be defective, $P(D)$, represent a Bernoulli distribution, thus $P(D_3|D_1,D_2)=P(D)$.

Comment: I'm given that the solution is in the form $$P(D_3|D_1 \cap D_2) = P(D_3|F_1)P(F_1|D_1 \cap D_2)  + P(D_3|F_2)P(F_2|D_1 \cap D_2) + P(D_3|F_3)P(F_3|D_1 \cap D_2)$$

Comment: Question for you: If you roll a die 3 times and the first two are $6$, what is the probability that the third roll will be a $6$? If you flip a coin two times and they happen to be heads, what is the probability that when you flip the coin a third time, it will be a head? If you pick three bolts and the first two are defective, how does that change the probability that the third one will be defective?

Comment: This would be a more interesting problem if the bolts were being selected from a *batch* that's from *one* of the factories (but not known), with $P(F_i)$ being the probability that the *batch* is from the $i$th factory. Then the solution form you're given would apply, and the probabilities $P(F_i\mid D_1D_2)$ would be found using Bayes' rule. (In that case the probability of the third bolt being defective would be affected by conditioning on the first two being defective, because that conveys information about which factory they're from.)